# jQuery.unique() not returning completely distinct values

Tags: jquery

I am using the 'jQuery.unique()' function to put distinct array values from one array to another array but the values in the 2nd array does not seem to contain distinct values.

```
var nonuniqueArray = ['AMI:8244','AMI:29126','AMI:31591','AMI:31591','AMI:31591','AMI:31591','AMI:29126'];
uniqueArray = $j.unique(nonuniqueArray);
alert (uniqueArray);
```

Values alerted are: `AMI:29126,AMI:31591,AMI:29126,AMI:8244`

I noticed that if similar values in the array are grouped together, then it works fine, for e.g if 'AMI:29126' are grouped together, it seems ok.

Any suggestion on what's wrong with the above code is most welcomed.

Many many thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's how you could do this with regular Array methods, but i would note that indexOf() is a newer array method and won't work in IE7 or earlier but is easily duplicated with 1 loop

```
var nonuniqueArray = ['AMI:8244','AMI:29126','AMI:31591','AMI:31591','AMI:31591','AMI:31591','AMI:29126'];

function distinctVal(arr){
    var newArray = [];
    for(var i=0, j=arr.length; i<j; i++){
        if(newArray.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1)
              newArray.push(arr[i]);  
    }
    return newArray;
}

var uniqueArray = distinctVal(nonuniqueArray);
alert(uniqueArray);
```

Answer (score 4):

The $.unique is not made for this see the following url: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/

> The $.unique() function searches through an array of objects, sorting
>   the array, and removing any duplicate nodes. **This function only works
>   on plain JavaScript arrays of DOM elements**, and is chiefly used
>   internally by jQuery.

What you can do is sort it first and then use unique, this is not exactly where it was made of, but it works.

```
var nonuniqueArray = ['AMI:8244','AMI:29126','AMI:31591','AMI:31591','AMI:31591','AMI:31591','AMI:29126'];
var sortedArray = Array.sort(nonuniqueArray );
var unique = $.unique(sortedArray);

$.each(unique , function(k, v){
    $("div").append(v + "<br />");
});
```

Result:

```
AMI:8244
AMI:31591
AMI:29126
```

LIVE DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/9x4dR/

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the jQuery `unique` method for arrays of Strings. It will only work on arrays of DOM elements. From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/):

> Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the duplicates removed.
>   Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or
>   numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample that's more efficient and compatible than Marlin's solution.  `indexOf` is a somewhat expensive lookup on large arrays, so for strings it's much better to create a temporary object:

```
function strUnique(arr) {
    var obj = {},
        ret = [],
        i   = arr.length;

    while (i--) {
        if (!obj[arr[i]]) {
            obj[arr[i]] = true;
            ret.unshift(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

If order is important, you may want to work forwards rather than backwards.  If so you'll need to adjust the loop accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 you can do something like this:

```
Array.prototype.unique = function() {
    let newArray = [];
    for(let i=0, j=this.length; i<j; i++){
        if(newArray.indexOf(this[i]) == -1) newArray.push(this[i]);
    }
    this.splice(0, this.length, ...newArray);
}
```

And just run it by `yourarray.unique()` (it works inplace). If you dont yse ES6 you can replace this: `this.splice(0, this.length, ...newArray);` by these lines (I not test this code below):

```
this.splice(0, this.length)
for(el of newArray) { this.push(el) }
```